What language is used to represent Pokolistani in Creature Commandos?
In Creature Commandos, there's a fictional European nation called Pokolistan whose citizens appear to speak in what sounds like a real European language.
According to the trivia section for Creature Commandos on IMDb, the language spoken in Pokolistan appears to be Bulgarian. However, this claim is not backed by any sources.
I'm curious whether they're actually speaking an existing European language, and if so, which one? Or is it perhaps a constructed language created specifically for the show?

According to James Gunn, Maria Bakalova was cast for the role of Princess Rostovic specifically because she speaks Bulgarian, which is what Gunn had in mind for the character.

Maria, I wrote for. She was the first person ever cast in the DCU.
So, I texted her because she speaks Bulgarian and we needed to have
Princess Rostovic, and we needed to hire everybody from that country,
and they needed to speak the same language, and we needed that to be
what Maria spoke.
James Gunn Reveals the Surprising Actor Who He Cast First In the New DCU

Other voice actors (including Julian Kostov) have confirmed that the lines are in Bulgarian.

Mom, dad… I’m in the @dcofficial universe! watch
@mariabakalovaofficial and I in CreatureCommandos on @streamonmax. We
voice most all citizens of Pokolistan who happen to speak Bulgarian
language!


I've found multiple tweets from Bulgarians who are excited about hearing Bulgarian spoken in the show.

The story unfolds within the familiar DCEU universe, with the timeline set shortly after the events of "The Suicide Squad 2." This time, Amanda Waller assembles a team of monsters and sends them on a mission to... Bulgaria!
Well, not exactly Bulgaria, but a fictional country where the princess
is voiced by @mariabakalovaofficial, and everyone speaks Bulgarian
(there’s something special about hearing your native language!).

